# imprimir variables provenientes de un for en python

Tags: python-3.x

tengo un problema al sacar variables provenientes de 2 for

cuando intento agregar las variables por ejemplo tengo 1 json donde estan los nombres y especialidades de cada individuo

en los nombres iria ejemplo:

```
pepito
pablo
diego
```

los cuales salen del del json al leerlos del for
pero mi problema viene cuando intento sacar la especialidad
y como vienen de otro for al intentar poner el nombre y la especialidad me sale por cada nombre

```
nombre = pepito
especialidad= kinesiologia
nombre = pepito 
especialidad = oftalmologia
```

y asi sucesivamente hasta acabar la lista de las especialidades y luego continua con el siguiente nombre y vuelve a agregar todas las especialidades al mismo nombre

mi codigo con el problema seria el siguiente

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests
import json
import subprocess
import ssl
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 
from xml.dom import minidom
data = []

if hasattr(ssl, '_create_unverified_context'):
    ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
url = 'https://......'

xml = urlopen(url)
xml_string = xml.read()
xml.close()
xmldoc = minidom.parseString(xml_string)
nombre=xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('nom')
especialidad=xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('nomEsp')
for nom in nombre: 
 nombremedico=nom.firstChild.nodeValue
 for esp in especialidad:
  especialidadmedico=esp.firstChild.nodeValue

  data.append({"name":nombremedico,"info":especialidadmedico})
with open('integramedica_maipu.json', 'w',encoding='utf-8') as f:  
 json.dump(data, f,indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
subprocess.run(["php", "helper_integramedica_maipu.php"])
```

alguna manito que me puedan dar? 
muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: El código que has pegado no se ve correcto. Quizás el primer for no debería estar indentado? Seguramente ha sido un problema al pegar el código en la pregunta. Mira este enlace para instrucciones de cómo hacerlo bien --> https://bit.ly/SOesPASTE. Por otro lado, ¿podrías proporcionar el valor de `xml_string` para que podamos probar a ejecutar tu código y ver por qué se comporta mal?

Comment: hola amigo gracias por tu ayuda he pegado el codigo completo

Comment: muchas gracias amigo ya quite el enlace :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, entiendo que en el XML que recibes tienes tantas entradas de tipo `nom` como de tipo `nomEsp`, y que ambas van "emparejadas", es decir, al primer nombre obtenido de `nom` le corresponde la primera especialidad obtenida de `nomEsp`.

En ese caso obviamente no debes ejecutar bucles anidados, pues por cada nombre en `nombre` recorrerías todas las especialidades en `especialidad`. Lo que necesitas es avanzar por ambas listas *a la vez* en paralelo, y no una dentro de otra.

Para eso puedes usar `zip()` al que le pasas una serie de iterables separados por comas y te devuelve otro iterador. Al iterar por el resultado devuelto por `zip()`, en cada iteración obtienes una tupla, con elementos sacados de la misma posición de los iterables recibidos.

En definitiva:

```
for nom, esp in zip(nombre, especialidad): 
  nombremedico=nom.firstChild.nodeValue
  especialidadmedico=esp.firstChild.nodeValue
  data.append({"name":nombremedico,"info":especialidadmedico})
```

En la primera iteración `nom` será el primer elemento de `nombre` y `esp` el primer elemento de `especialidad`. En la segunda iteración, serán los segundos elementos respectivamente, etc. El bucle termina cuando la lista más corta se acabe, si bien en este caso son iguales.

Un ejemplo de lo que obtienes en `data`:

```
[{'name': 'JILES MEZA LIZETTE ANGELICA', 'info': 'ENDODONCIA'},
 {'name': 'REBOLLEDO SCHMIDT ERWIN EUGENIO', 'info': 'PSICOLOGIA ADULTOS'}, 
 {'name': 'SCHADE FIERRO SIGRID ALEJANDRA', 'info': 'ODONTOLOGIA GENERAL INFANTIL'},
 etc...
]
```

Comment: muchas gracias lo habia intentado con zip pero me daba un error y ya vi cual era muchisimas gracias